# ffmpeg - Problem with zoompan

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a video from a set of images, adding texts to each image that slide from one side to the center ( one left to right, another right to left ), with fading between each videos ( not between text but between video ).

Actually I have this code that generare a simple video, with text sliding and fade:

```
ffmpeg -y \
    -loop 1 -t 10 -i img001.jpg  \
    -loop 1 -t 10 -i img002.jpg  \
-filter_complex \
"\
[0:v]\
drawtext=fontfile='IndieFlower.ttf':enable='between(t,0,5)':\
text='Caption 1 Scena 1':\
fontsize=60:fontcolor=white:\
x=t*300*lte(t*300\,(w-text_w)/2)+(w-text_w)/2*gt(t*300\,(w-text_w)/2):y=h-line_h-10:\
shadowx=3:shadowy=3:shadowcolor=black:\
boxborderw=10:box=1:boxcolor=red@0.8,\
drawtext=fontfile='IndieFlower.ttf':enable='between(t,5,10)':\
text='Caption 2 Scena 1':\
fontsize=60:fontcolor=white:\
x=(w-(t-5)*500)*gt(w-(t-5)*500\,(w-text_w)/2)+(w-text_w)/2*lte(w-(t-5)*500\,(w-text_w)/2):y=h-line_h-10:\
shadowx=3:shadowy=3:shadowcolor=black:\
boxborderw=10:box=1:boxcolor=red@0.8\
[final1];\
[1:v]\
fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,\
drawtext=fontfile='IndieFlower.ttf':enable='between(t,0,5)':\
text='Caption 1 Scena 2':\
fontsize=60:fontcolor=red:\
x=t*300*lte(t*300\,(w-text_w)/2)+(w-text_w)/2*gt(t*300\,(w-text_w)/2):y=h-line_h-10:\
shadowx=3:shadowy=3:shadowcolor=white:\
boxborderw=10:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8,\
drawtext=fontfile='IndieFlower.ttf':enable='between(t,5,10)':\
text='Caption 2 Scena 2':\
fontsize=60:fontcolor=red:\
x=(w-(t-5)*500)*gt(w-(t-5)*500\,(w-text_w)/2)+(w-text_w)/2*lte(w-(t-5)*500\,(w-text_w)/2):y=h-line_h-10:\
shadowx=3:shadowy=3:shadowcolor=white:\
boxborderw=10:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8\
[final2];\
[final1][final2]concat[final]
" \
-pix_fmt yuvj422p -t 20 -map '[final]' o.mp4
```

It works well, but now, I'd like to add a `zoompan` effect to both of the images; so I change the code as follow:

```
[0:v]\
format=yuvj422p,
scale=iw*10:ih*10,\
zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=500:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2 (ih/zoom/2)':s=640x480,\
drawtext=fontfile='IndieFlower.ttf':enable='between(t,0,5)':\

...

[1:v]\
format=yuvj422p,
scale=iw*10:ih*10, \
zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=500:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=640x480,\
fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,\
...
```

but this does not work; in the final video there is only the first "video", with the zoompan, the second video does not appear at all!

What I'm doing wrong? I'd like to create a simple zoompan between two video.

Answer (score 3):

`zoompan` is a weirdly designed filter. It operates on individual frames, whereas most filters operate on a sequence of pictures, whether they are fed from a video file or an image sequence. `pzoom` should be used for a looped image, and frame sequence generation should be stopped by making d=1.

Change to

```
zoompan=z='min(pzoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2 (ih/zoom/2)':s=640x480
```

This will fix the zoompan.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Really Thanks! I just have these messages:
`[swscaler @ 0x7f3d60016880] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly`, I'm using `-pix_fmt yuvj422p`, is not correct?

Comment: For final output, `yuv420p` is standard.

Comment: Thanks, it works. To finish my job, I need to add an mp3 to the process. Should I open a new Ask Question, or you can suggest me how to add this new input to the command above? I tryed adding `[final1][final2][2:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[finalVideo][finalAudio]` but it does not work ( mp3 is the third input )

Comment: You don't need to add the audio to the concat. Remove the `-map [final]`